# Javascript document is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, domdocument

I have this error and I don't understand why:  `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.
I tried to put `window.content.document`, but error `window` is not defined too. 
I don't know where is the trick and specially I don't understand why?
Worst when I take it off, I have as error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` whereas I included jQuery in my html.

this is my script.js:

```
var client = {};

client.start = function (data) {

    setTimeout(function(data) {
    client.chart(data);
    }, 60);
};

module.exports.getJson= function(data){

    client.start(data);
};

client.chart= function (data) {

    //console.log(" this is the data" + data);

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(function () {
          //Do my stuff
        });
    });
};
```

and my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/sprinkle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="containerChart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you load two versions of jQuery?

Comment: I think (s)he lifted the code where they load the library scripts.

Comment: Sorry, I removed one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have `document` object inside your script so remove below code from script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
      //Do my stuff
    });
});
```

Instead of above code, you can call your script function from html page like below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //call your script.js function from here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I hardly think that is correct.. I cannot reproduce it, have never seen that problem, and it is not mentioned here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 5):

The proper answer, I believe, is that the linter you are using, does not know that you are running in a browser environment. Objects such as document and window are predefined. Personally, I had this issue with eslint and I fixed it by doing the following:

```
env: {
        browser: true
      }
```

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: it is env not envs according to eslint config guide http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments

Comment: `ReferenceError` does not come from a linter but from actually running the code. You seem to have a solution for a different problem.